# Azure Developer User consent to app accessing company data

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working with an organization that has disabled user consent for azure apps.
**"Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf"** is set to **No** in the Azure Portal.

I would like developers to be able to give consent to they own apps in azure without setting the above setting to yes. (the apps needs the "*Sign in and read user profile*" delegated permissions Azure AD).

1: Is it correct that the only other way is the assign the developers to one of the Azure AD roles that has one of these permissions: Application Developer, Application Administrator or Cloud Application Administrator?

2: I would also like to automate this process during a AzureDevOps release pineline. Currently the release pipeline creates all needed Azure resources via ARM Templates.

But how do I automate the **App Registration** without going to the Portal? 
And how do I ensure that the release pipeline has the correct Azure AD permission to **give consent**?
Can I force the Pipeline to run as an "Azure AD Service User that I give the above role?

**Update 1**

It seems that its possible to do Azure AD Registration with powershell. http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2017/09/13/creating-azure-ad-app-registration-with-powershell-part-1

Since the AzureAD is using MFA, the script will display an interactive credential dialog when running. Not sure if we can suppress that.

**Update 2**

And give app consent with powershell. https://www.mavention.nl/blogs-cat/create-azure-ad-app-registration-with-powershell-part-2/?cn-reloaded=1

**Update 3**

So to automate the whole process, I was thinking if we could use a **Azure DevOps Service Connection** to execute these powershell scripts during the release pipeline?

Not sure what permission is needed for the Azure DevOps Service Connection?

It should also suppress the MFA credential dialog.

Comment: What permissions (specifically) do you need developers to be able to consent to, and are these permissions delegated permissions, or app-only permissions?

Comment: The "Sign in and read user profile" delegated permissions.

Comment: For themselves only, or for all users in the tenant (including users who are not in the same role)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct that the only other way is the assign the developers to one of the Azure AD roles that has this permission: Application Developer, Application Administrator or Cloud Application Administrator?

It depends on the permissions the app is requesting, and who you would like the developers to be consenting for (themselves, or the entire organization):

- Members of the *Application Developer* directory role can consent only to delegated permissions (not application permissions), and only on behalf of themselves (not on behalf of the entire tenant). Only other members of this role would be able to use the app (they would each consent on behalf of themselves), and only if the permissions requested are user-consentable delegated permissions. If your only requirement is for developers to be able to get delegated `User.Read` permission to Microsoft Graph, then this would work.
- Members of the *Application Administrator* and *Cloud Application Administrator* directory roles can consent on behalf of all users for both delegated permissions and app-only permissions, except for app-only permissions to Azure AD or Microsoft Graph. These roles are both *very* privileged, and it is unlikely you would want the average developer to posses this--certainly not if the only permission needed is delegated `User.Read`.

> But how do I automate the App Registration without going to the Portal?

With the Microsoft Graph API, you can register an app by [creating an Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta). As of 2018-12-05, this is still in beta in Microsoft Graph.

If you require a production-ready endpoint, [the Azure AD Graph API supports this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity), which is what's used by the various command-line and PowerShell options: [`New-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0), [`az ad app create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create), and [`New-AzureRmADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-6.13.0).

To do this without a user involved, the client application (the one creating the app registration) requires the `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` application permission, at minimum.

> And how do I ensure that the release pipeline has the correct Azure AD permission to give consent?

This is where things get complicated. While it is possible to create the app registration (the Application object) as described above, these is currently no application permission that would allow an app to grant consent for another app. Though there is work underway to allow for "normal" application permissions to allow one app to grant other apps some permissions, currently only members of the directory roles authorized to consent to these permissions are able to perform this action.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So for the automation of the consent, I assume that the Directory.ReadWrite.All permission will not work.  Would it work if we give the "AzureDevOps Service Connection/Principle" the AD Application Administrator role? That way only "scripts" during the Release pipeline has this elevated permission and not all Devs.

Comment: A more secure solution might be to create an internal service that runs as "Application Administrator" and that service can only do one thing: "Create App registration". We could then expose and endpoint and call this service from the release pipeline.

Comment: I'm more partial to the second approach, which will allow you to better isolate the (over)privileged service, until a more appropriate application permission is available. Needless to say: be very careful about how you expose such an service, use appropriate authentication and authorization, and look out for privilege elevation risks (e.g. can it be misused such that a user is able to grant themselves, or an app they control, more permissions than they should be able to?)

Comment: When thinking about it, we will first try to see if the "Application Developer" role will work for us. We will just need to give it to all devs and testers. As a side note, this doc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-applications-are-added#who-has-permission-to-add-applications-to-my-azure-ad-instance says this Microsoft internally use the default settings (allow consent for all users). I can understand that this is not the case anymore. Maybe this is the reason for this new "Application Developer" role :-)